# Find subsequence of K elements with a given sum

Tags: arrays, algorithm, language-agnostic

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sum-subset with a fixed subset size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8916539/sum-subset-with-a-fixed-subset-size)

So I have an array `A`, with elements `A[1], A[2] .. A[N]`

I want to find a subsequence (not necessarily contiguous), with exactly `K` elements, whose sum is exactly `Sum`.

My best guess is of O(N<sup>K</sup>), if you run K nested loops, and test every possibility.

Can this be done faster?

All elements of `A` are integers, greater than 0.

Comment: Are the elements positive integers?

Comment: @wye.bee, yes, integers `> 0`.

Answer (score 1):

I think this cannot be solved in polinomial time. @Anderson is right, it does resemble the knapsack problem.

Although you can make it faster by a [branch and bound](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_and_bound) algorithm, but it's effectiveness will be based on your actual values. (eg: if you exceed the sum, don't test further)

**Edit:**
Based on the topic, what @amit linked, O(n^k) is indeed the best answer, which is polinomial in n, for any fixed k value.