# Find lexicographically smallest string with given hash value [Competitive Coding]

Tags: string, hash, dynamic-programming

I encountered the following problem for which I couldn't quite find the appropriate solution.

> > The problem says for a given string having a specific hash value, find the lowest string (which is not the same as the given one) of the
> >     same length and same hash value (if one exists).
> >  E.g. For the
> >     following value mapping of alphabets:
> >  {a:0, b:1, c:2,...,z:25}
> >     If the given string is: ady with hash value - 27. The
> >     lexicographically smallest one (from all possible ones excluding the
> >     given one) would be: acz

**Solution approach I could think of:**
I reduced the problem to Coin-Change problem and resorted to finding all possible combinations for the given sum. Out of all the obtained solutions, I sort them up and find the lowest (or the next smallest if the given string is smallest).
The problem however lies with finding all possible solutions (even in a DP approach) which might be inefficient for larger inputs.

**My doubt is**:
 
What solution strategy (possibly even Greedy) could give a better time complexity than above?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot guarantee that this will give you a lower complexity, but a couple of things:1 you don't need to check all the space, just the space of lexicographic value less than or equal to the given string. 2: you can formulate it as an integer programming problem:

Assuming your character space is the letters, and each letter is given its number index[0-25] so a corresponds to 0, b to 1 and so forth. let x_i be the number of letters in your string corresponding to index i. You can formulate your problem as:

```
min sum_i(wi*xi)
st xi*ai = M
xi>=0,
sum_i(xi)=n
sum_i(wi*xi)<= N
xi integer
```

Where `wi= 26^i`, `ai` is equal to `hash(letter(i))`, n is the number of letters of the original string, `N` is the hash value of the original string. This is an integer programming problem so you can try plugging it to a solver. The original problem is very similar to [subset sum problem with fixed subset size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8916539/sum-subset-with-a-fixed-subset-size) (where the hash values are the elements you are summing over, and the subset size is the length of the string) so you might also want to take a look at that, although as you will see from the answer it is a complicated problem.